# uncaught Error: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.10.7:19000

Tags: react-native, expo

I was working on my expo app, and yesterday, totally at random, when I was launching "expo start" and then scan the QR code to see my app, this error appeared. I am now unable to access my app through a LAN connection, it works fine with Tunnel but I really don't understand why this happened.

Again, it happened at random after a day of normal work where everything was working fine. Did anyone have the same issue?

Comment: it's work on the tunnel but why it's not working on LAN someone, please answer

Comment: I have the exact same issue, no solution found yet :(

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue. Make sure your computer and mobile are connected to the same Internet Network.

In my case my mobile and computer, both were connected to different Wifi networks. So make sure that both the devices are connected to the same network.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is open a Hotspot from your computer and then connect your mobile device to the Hotspot, the error will go away. That is what I did when I encountered the same error.